# Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: Teradata 16.20

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am trying to connect to tera database from the spring boot application. When i run the service, I receive the below error log:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: Teradata 16.20
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DatabaseType.fromDatabaseProductNameAndPostgreSQLVersion(DatabaseType.java:168) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DatabaseType.fromJdbcConnection(DatabaseType.java:117) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:90) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1670) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.ford.cloudnative.base.app.datasource.populate.DataSourcePopulateConfiguration$FlywayMigrator.migrate(DataSourcePopulateConfiguration.java:138) ~[spring-base-app-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.ford.cloudnative.base.app.datasource.populate.DataSourcePopulateConfiguration$DataSourcePopulatorInitializer.initializeDataSource(DataSourcePopulateConfiguration.java:118) ~[spring-base-app-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.ford.cloudnative.base.app.datasource.populate.DataSourcePopulateConfiguration$DataSourcePopulatorInitializer.initialize(DataSourcePopulateConfiguration.java:88) ~[spring-base-app-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you please format the log output and give a minimal code snippet which is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway does not support Teradata yet. Here is the pending Pull Request:

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1655